# php query returns missing data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my php query for getting data. Let me explain what I want. I have a database which saves the active users for some hours in a day. For example 01-01-2012 13:00
active = 5 01-01-2012 14:00 active = 10. My php query should make an array which contains 2 columns which are date and active. But date must be like 01-01-2012 withour hours. So I grouped them as date2 but I couldn't find the active(sum) for each days. Here is my query which doesn't give the right active sums.

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date2, SUM(active) FROM hit WHERE game= '".$game."' AND source = '".$source."' AND date > '".$dateFrom."' AND date < '".$dateTo."' GROUP BY date2 ORDER BY date2");

while($tuple=  mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
    $myArr[] = $tuple;
}
print_r($myArr);
```

Comment: Please could you expand on your question with full working example code. Currently the question does not indicate what type of object `$dateFrom` is and what the other variable values are and there in no information about the SQL column types

Comment: Since you're using the deprecated `mysql_query` interface, you must escape all of your values using `mysql_real_escape_string` or you have **severe** [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobb-tables.com/php). It's much easier to ensure your application is safe using `mysqli` or PDO. You should switch to one of these interfaces before it's too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alias `SUM(active)` and `GROUP BY date`. If `date` is a `datetime`, you can `GROUP BY DATE(date)`. Also, be careful with [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and make sure to use tick marks where necessary.

Further, if you are looking for an inclusive date range, you should know that when you send `2012-10-03`, it is actually `2012-10-03 00:00:00` and any records between `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` will be ignored.

Lastly, you should stop using `mysql_` functions as they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com).

This [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b37cf/1) should work:

```
$query2 = mysql_query("
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date2, SUM(active) AS active 
    FROM hit 
    WHERE game= '".$game."' AND source = '".$source."' 
        AND `date` > DATE_SUB('".$dateFrom."', INTERVAL 1 SECOND) 
        AND `date` < DATE_ADD('".$dateTo."', INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
    ORDER BY `date`");
$i = 0;
while($tuple=  mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
    $myArr[$i][date2] = $tuple[date2];
    $myArr[$i][active] = $tuple[active];
    $i++;
}
print_r($myArr);
```

Your array (`$myArr`) would then look something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date2] => 2012-10-03
            [active] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: it didnt work. It gives 01-01-2012 and 01-01-2012 and again and again. It should group them as 01-01-2012 once and should add summation of actives in that array. I mean it should give day by day active users(summation)

Comment: @AnılCanlı I just made an update. Also, What is the format of the date for `$dateFrom` and `$dateTo`?

Comment: it still gives like thisArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-09-01
            [date2] => 2012-09-01
            [1] => 0
            [active] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-09-01
            [date2] => 2012-09-01
            [1] => 0
            [active] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-09-01
            [date2] => 2012-09-01
            [1] => 0
            [active] => 0
        )

Comment: @AnılCanlı Can you take a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b37cf/1) fiddle and see why it may not be working on your end?

Comment: create table hit (
  game tinyint,
  source tinyint,
  date datetime,
  active tinyint);

insert into hit values 
(1, 1, '2012-10-05 15:14:13', 1),
(1, 1, '2012-10-04 15:14:13', 5),
(1, 1, '2012-10-01 15:14:13', 8),
(1, 1, '2012-10-06 14:34:13', 9),
(1, 1, '2012-10-06 15:24:15', 10),
(1, 1, '2012-10-06 12:15:13', 11)  try this you will see the result will be 2012-10-06 three times.

Comment: @AnılCanlı Ah, just need to change to `GROUP BY DATE(date)`. See updated answer.

Comment: [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-09-17
            [date2] => 2012-09-17
            [1] => 0
            [active] => 0
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-09-18
            [date2] => 2012-09-18
            [1] => 0
            [active] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2012-09-19
            [date2] => 2012-09-19
            [1] => 168
            [active] => 168
        ) aham its grouped as i did before but active didn't work again. It gives the summation of active in the last element of array not date by date :/

Comment: @AnılCanlı Perhaps try explicitly defining the array key, see my edit.

Comment: nope still the same it gives the summation in the last element :|

Comment: 19Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date2] => 2012-09-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [active] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date2] => 2012-09-02
        ) it goes like this and i = 19; @njk